# How to write constructor of derived template cpp class in Cython?

Tags: inheritance, constructor, cython

I have a template class A and a derived class B:

`test.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

namespace test {

template <typename T1>
class A {
    T1 a;
public:
    A(T1 _a) : a(_a) { }
    virtual ~A() { }
};

class B : public A<int> {
public:
    B(int a) : A<int>(a) { }
    virtual ~B() { }
};

}
```

It can be compiled.

Then I try to write a cython script to expose both A and B:

`test.pyx`:

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "test.hpp" namespace "test":
    cdef cppclass A[T1]:
        A(T1)
    cdef cppclass B(A):
        B(int)
```

Then I got a compile error:

```
test.pyx:7:10: no matching function for call to A::A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx"),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 825, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 944, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
```

I notice that if the class `A` is not template, then there is no error. Any advice about how to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* Cython is expecting a null constructor, but it does.

Note that the problem is nothing to do with templates; the problem is purely that Cython wants a null constructor. Try removing the template and keeping it so the constructor has an argument and the error persists.

One way to do it is pretend that it exists:

```
cdef cppclass A[T1]:
    A()
    A(T1)
cdef cppclass B(A[int]):
    B(int)
```

This will error with

```
FILENAME: error: no matching function for call to ‘test::A<int>::A()’
   __pyx_v_a = new test::A<int>();
```

if the null constructor is ever inadvertently called, so it's safe... it's just ugly.

When you have this, code like:

```
cdef A[int] *a = new B(4)
```

works as you would expect.